# Jasmine angular how to spy on $setDirty function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I want to test angular foreach function on form scope. I get error 'type error' field.$setDirty is not a function. How to test this foreach? 
My fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f0dk2r5v/)

My foreach and test

```
  angular.forEach($scope.form.ctrl.$error.required, function (field) {
                    field.$setDirty();
                });



 it('test angular foreach', function () {
        var field = {
            $setDirty: jasmine.createSpy('$setDirty')
        };
         scope.form = {
            ctrl: {
                $valid: jasmine.createSpy('$valid'),
                $error: {required: {test:'test'}}
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I was so stupid.. i should provide `$invalid = false` into form to go on